# MySQL: Column count doesn't match value count. syntaxis error

Tags: mysql, syntax, mysql-error-1136

I've looked at a couple questions similar to this, but none seem to be what I'm looking for. These are the values that I'm getting an error for.

```
insert into Artist(artistId, artistName)
values(
(1,"Artist1"),
(2,"Artist2"),
(3,"Artist3"),
(4,"Artist4"),
(5,"Artist5"),
(6,"Artist6"),
(7,"Artist7"),
(8,"Artist8"),
(9,"Artist9"),
(10,"Artist10"));
```

Is it possible that there is a syntax error further up in my code that could be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove parentheses:

```
insert into Artist(artistId, artistName)
values
(1,"Artist1"),
(2,"Artist2"),
(3,"Artist3"),
(4,"Artist4"),
(5,"Artist5"),
(6,"Artist6"),
(7,"Artist7"),
(8,"Artist8"),
(9,"Artist9"),
(10,"Artist10");
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f79dc/1/0)**</kbd>

[`INSERT syntax`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

```
INSERT INTO tab(column_list)
VALUES (row_1_value_list), (row_2_value_list), ...;
```

Comment: (Parentheses), [brackets] and {braces}. ;) It *is* the right answer, though. :)

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax Thanks for distinction. I use brackets (meaning round/simple brackets)

Comment: I was trying to get the query to fold up into one line to avoid scrolling through 100s of insert columns. Is there a way that I could achieve this?

Comment: @JacobFillmore Just remove line breaks `insert into Artist(artistId, artistName) values(1,"Artist1"),(2,"Artist2"),(3,"Artist3"),(4,"Artist4"),(5,"Artist5"),(6,"Artist6"),(7,"Artist7"),(8,"Artist8"),(9,"Artist9"),(10,"Artist10");` It can be one-liner as well

Comment: Then you need to scroll over to be able to see it all though :( I was hoping I could collapse/expand it when needed. Thanks for the help.